# GeoServer and MapServer annotation feature

Tags: gis, geoserver, mapserver

I am evaluating 2 products GeoServer and MapServer at this moment for a mapping solution. One of the requirement is to enable end users to annotate map with text, lines and symbology and then save it as a file perferred image file to be embedded on a form. Is this requirement achievable using either products? If yes which exact area/class I should look into?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using SLD for your WMS from MapServer and GeoServer.

Both system supports this ogc standard technology and it fits what you are looking for. It is stored in an external xml like file that easy to be stored and transferred.

Plus, SLD is very powerful to integrate with spatial/ non spatial filter to make precise and detail control of the symbology of your service.